# Fade in Object, but without the need of animate the texture or material

Tags: animation, objects, geometry

Is there any way to Fade in and Fade Out an object via ID or Group? (not Material itself?)

I'm doing an scene on Eevee by rendering everything via viewport render (the quality is schematic so that's enough) where a building is being build by the parts appearing like bricks, but i need them to fade in when they appear, is there any solution for this inside the software itself?

Also, fade in a collection would work for this too.

Comment: maybe build modifier?

Comment: I cant do that since i need it like 3 objects moving on specific ways this time.

Comment: what about compositing?